# Sql with json, dynamic multiple product type with dynamic multiple attributes with multiple collection values

Tags: json, sql-server, database-normalization

I’m looking for best practices to create ERD (SQL Server) in 2019 for following example.

I have a multiple products (car like renault, opel) - about 100 000 records.
Each product has series e.g (clio, laguna), each series has a car model e.g (I, II, III)

[image]

[image]

Each car model has a lot of attributes with multiple values (mostly collection values) e.g

[image: Diagram Car model attribute and values]

As you can see on the diagram some attributes have one value some have collections values. Some attributes have the same name in different car model, some are new.
Values in attributes often repeat but they are also specific for the model

In my real model, attributes and values will change few times a month for each product.

So my question is: What is the best practices to create db schema? (I use SQL Server 2017 and ASPNET.CORE for backend API)

Below I show you my solutions:

1. First EAV pattern. (For clarity I didn’t separate value types (varchar, bool, int, etc.) into separate tables): I’m not a supporter of this solution

[image]

2. Create table for each series Model.

[image]

But what next? Mostly attributes has a collection values. Should I use in this case for each attribute json values? E.g  {"length": ["4848", "5000", "5005"]}.
Despite of EAV pattern and keep the base normalized 1NF I think about create for each attribute separate table with values and create relationship to car models (I, II, III), but the number of table will be huge.

3. Sparse table as JSON column for values collection

[image]

[image]

4. Create JsonObject column in SeriesModel table with the following json structure:

   ```
   {
    "III" :
       {
       "length": ["4848", "5000", "5005"],
       "UpholsteryColor" : ["black", "bronze"],
       "Color" : ["blue", "black", "green"]
       }
   }
   ```

[image]

5. Create only two tables Car and BrandSeries, in BrandSeries I added JsonObject column with following json structure

   ```
    {
   "III" :
     {
   "length": ["4848", "5000", "5005"],
   "UpholsteryColor" : ["black", "bronze"],
   "Color" : ["blue", "black", "green"]
   },
   "II" :
     {
   "length": ["4000", "5000"],
   "UpholsteryColor" : ["black", "bronze"],
   "Color" : ["blue", "violet"],
   "GasCar" : 1
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have choosen option nr 4, but any suggestions will be appreciated.